# Accidentally spent unconfirmed funds, when will they clear?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

I accidentally rushed when transferring some funds from my wallet before they had been fully confirmed, now the transaction has been unconfirmed for quite some time and I was wondering how long it might take to process?

Is there some way to cancel the previous transaction and execute another one now the funds are confirmed?

The transaction has the following id: aa7bd2ad6657dad1c2152edf6d7fdfd59cbc4e4385a792f741b50b32bcf68be1

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fee is too small. So, it will take many hours to be confirmed.

Don't worry, the second transaction will be confirmed after the confirmation of the first one.
It will take many hours, but they will be confirmed.